# “of my heart” vs “in my heart” and how to use prepositions correctly

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'm not a native speaker, and the uses of prepositions are driving me crazy.

I saw a post with the phrase "you are the champion of my heart" on it.
I thought it should be "the champion in my heart", "of my heart" sounds like you have several hearts, and one of them is your champion...
Then I googled it, found out this "of my hearts" usage got more results than "in".
The same question goes for "Secret of my heart" and "secret in my heart".

I read some grammar books, there were a lot of examples for prepositions, but still cannot cover all of the situations. Are there any rules about how to use prepositions correctly or I just have to remember every case I've met?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, "of my heart" simply means that something is associated with your emotions:

> You are the love **of my heart**.

Also, when we use words like "heart" or "head" metaphorically, prepositions may not mean what you think they mean. Consider:

> You really got **in my head** for a minute there.

That simply means, "You affected my thoughts," and (thankfully) has nothing to do with you shrinking and climbing into my skull.

As for "of my heart" vs. "in my heart", here's one way I might characterize the two:

- *of my heart* can be used with the definite article, to **indicate preeminent personal feelings**
- *in my heart* can be used with the indefinite article, to **project a role**

For example:

> **You are a diva in my heart**.  (means: *in my heart, I regard you as a diva*)
>   **You are the diva of my heart**. (means: *in my heart, I regard you as* **the** *diva*)

So, back to what you said:

> "of my heart" sounds like you have several hearts, and one of them is your champion...

Instead:

> ***the*** champion of my heart

means something more like:

> *there may be several people who **could** be my champion, but, in my heart, you are my **true** champion*

---

**Disclaimer**: I wouldn't regard this as a hard-and-fast rule with zero exceptions. As was mentioned, prepositions are *very* tricky. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/of) lists more than 20 possible usages of the word *of*, and when you combine those with metaphorical words such as *head, heart* or *skin*, some preposition-noun combinations will indeed be idiomatic, and need to be learned one-by-one (such as, "She really gets [under my skin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/under+one%27s+skin).")

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean "The champion in my hearts" is not correct, it should be "(A) champion in my heart"?

Comment: I can't say if five words put together is "correct" or not; it depends on the context. I'd be inclined to think that "the champion in **our** hearts" would probably be better, since the plural _hearts_ suggests more than one person. But who knows? In children's literature, for example, an earthworm might say, "You saved me from the mean old robin! You are the champion in my hearts."

Answer (score -2):

To make *secret* thing clear, take a look...

> *"The secret **of** my heart is my heart has one extra valve! I have not disclosed this to anyone! **OVER***
>
> *"I will keep the secret **in** my heart that you unknowingly murdered someone. Don't worry, I'll carry this to my grave."*

In this case, something ***of*** the heart means it's related to the heart whereas ***in*** the heart defines *heart* as a place.

As far as the sentence *you are the champion of my heart* is concerend, it depends on the context. It may mean that *he won the heart of yours.* Now that *win* may come by any means.

**Or** it may mean that someone, being the champion of your heart, is protecting you. He fights for you and saves you from difficulties. In other words, if **the champion of your heart** is there, you are taken care of. You fully trust him as he's the champion of your heart.

[There's a song](http://tunesmith.net/forums/showthread.php?14433-Champion-of-My-Heart) which refers to the latter meaning. Pasting a portion from there

> I had a dream about us 
>  
>   And the first night we met
>  
>   Sipping wine in the moonlight
>  
>   There on your backporch steps
>
> First time I'd seen the ocean
>  
>   And smelled the salty sea
>  
>   And the atmosphere around us
>  
>   Was thick as the humidity
>
> *Chorus:*
>
> And you've just got to know
>  
>   You're the **Champion of my heart**
>  
>   Your warm and loving soul
>  
>   Guides me **safely thru the dark**
>  
>   Your gentleness gives reason
>  
>   **To trust** in all you do
>  
>   And yes you are
>  
>   **The Champion of my heart**

A side but good note: Don't rely on the *number* of Google results.

Comment: *Champion* could well mean something else entirely here, especially since *my heart* doesn't lend itself well to being a contest. *Champion of my heart* might mean *someone who fights for my feelings* - check [the definitions of champion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/champion).

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I did not want to get into the *way* of winning the heart. Anyway, to avoid ambiguity, I am editing the answer.

Comment: The included song lyrics are about *protecting* the heart and its feelings (e.g. from darkness) and not *winning* it (in any sense).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interesting samples :). So, does it mean "champion of my heart" and "champion in my heart" is little difference in use? For example, someone lost the game, you can either say "you are the champion in my heart" or "you are the champion of my heart"?

Comment: @Liam In such case, I guess we use *to*. *So what if you have lost; to my heart, you are, and will be the champion.*

Comment: @EsotericScreenName what did I say then? The *latter* means *protecting*. You probably missed my answer.

Comment: @MaulikV Thank.But maybe I didn't describe the scene correctly. I meant, can we say "you are the champion of my heart"/"you are the champion in my heart", to __the one who have lost__ the game?

Comment: @Liam nope, I won't vote for that. I'll use *to* instead.

Comment: @Liam there is a difference between the two prepositions. *In my heart* means *to me and my feelings, you are the champion* and is likely to use champion in the sense of *winner*. *Of my heart* must use champion in the sense of *protector*, because one's heart is not a contest.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Thanks! After reading all of the answers and comments, I'm not sure about everything now LOL. It seems like they both right, so I might just give up on dwelling on this question...